# duplicate on my PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

Here's my code sir:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'include/db_config.php';

    $result = $dbs->prepare("SELECT * FROM service_info ORDER BY id DESC");
    /*$result->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id']);*/
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

    $result2 = $dbs->prepare("SELECT *FROM customer_info ORDER BY id DESC");
    $result2->execute();
    for($j=0; $row2 = $result2->fetch();$j++){


?>


<tr class="record">
    <td><?php echo $row2['firstname'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['no_guest']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type_service']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['datepicker']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['t_time']; ?></td>

    <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> delete </a></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

i didnt use a LEFT JOIN for displaying data's from 2 tables. i just want to do it in my own way . But my problem is it duplicates my data . before i inserted my second query its just 2 data's and now its 4 already. i just cant figure it out where is the duplication occurs.

Someone help me out please . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add an example please

Comment: Is something common to join these two table ? Show us schema of both table ?

Comment: you mean sir my database?

Comment: Yes sir, I think joining would be better.

Comment: actually sir i dont know how to use joins .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You display data in second `for`, which is inside first `for`. So you get result count of customer_info table length*service_info length results. You should save info in arrays and then use only one `for` cycle. Eg.:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        include 'include/db_config.php';
        $services = array();
        $customers = array();
        $result = $dbs->prepare("SELECT * FROM service_info ORDER BY id DESC");
        /*$result->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id']);*/
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
            $services[] = $row;
        }
        $result2 = $dbs->prepare("SELECT *FROM customer_info ORDER BY id DESC");
        $result2->execute();
        for($j=0; $row2 = $result2->fetch();$j++){
          $customers[] = $row2;
        }
        foreach($services as $key => $service) {
    ?>


    <tr class="record">
        <td><?php echo $customers[$key]['firstname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $service['no_guest']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $service['type_service']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $service['datepicker']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $service['t_time']; ?></td>

        <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $service['id']; ?>"> delete </a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Btw, i suggest you use different approach, like `joins`

Comment: so i just need to add this line of code? $customers[]= $row2;

Comment: Take a better look at code, because it's changed in many places.

Comment: it says  FATAL ERROR: CANNOT USE OBJECT OF TYPE PDOSTATEMENT AS ARRAY IN C:\WAMP\WWW\SPAFINALS\VIEWRESERVATION.PHP ON LINE 83

Comment: the $customers[$key] is invalid i guess . i cant be an array it says

Comment: Try changing: `$services[] = $row;` to `array_push($services,$row);` and `$customers[] = $row2;` to `array_push($customers,$row2);`